# How can I query mysql table and display result using php conditional statements

Tags: php, mysql

I want to show user that he has vaccinated his goat after successfully payment confirmation.
Here is what I tried:

```
<?php
$treatperiod1=$product_row['treat1'];
$currentDate = date("Y-m-d");
$totalDays = $treatperiod1;
$usedDays = round(abs(strtotime($currentDate)-strtotime($orderdate))/60/60/24);
$remainingDays = $totalDays-$usedDays;

if($remainingDays==0) {
    echo "<a target = '_blank' href ='product_addon.php?treatp=$treatperiod1' class='btn btn-success'><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i>Vaccinate Gaoat</a>";
} elseif($remainingDays==$treatperiod1) {
    echo 'Vaccinated';
} else {
    echo $remainingDays.' Days Left';         
}

?>
```

I have displayed remaining days for vaccination intervals I want to also display 'Vaccinated' if user payment for vaccination is confirmed. `$product_row['treat1'];` is a column where the number of days for vaccination is specified. `order_details` is a table for orders with column confirm for confirmed orders.

Comment: if a user 'vaccinetes' the goat, do you save anything on you DB?

Comment: Yes, in order_details table under confirm

Comment: I have tried this but could not work elseif($remainingDays==0 || $order_status=='Delivered')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goat Vaccination:
*Because Goats don't get Autism*

Please read [how to use PHP DateTime objects](https://paulund.co.uk/datetime-php) because they will make your life a lot easier on this project.

I will rewrite your code and then tell you what the new code does:

```
//establish DateTime objects. 
$currentDate = new DateTime(); //now.
$orderDate   = new DateTime($orderdate); //$orderdate format Y-m-d

//Establish how may days since order date and today.
$difference  = $orderDate->diff($currentDate);
$usedDays    = $difference->days;  

/*** 
 Total Period paid for,
 in days, integer.  
 $product_row['treat1'];
 ***/

 $remainingDays = $product_row['treat1'] - $usedDays;
 //Returns an integer value of remaining days. 


if($remainingDays < 1) {
    echo "<a target = '_blank' 
          href ='product_addon.php?treatp=".$treatperiod1."'>
          Vaccinate Goat</a>";
} elseif($remainingDays==$product_row['treat1']) {
    //This will only fire if the goat was vaccinated TODAY.
    echo 'Vaccinated';
} else {
    echo 'Vaccinated:' .$remainingDays.' Days Left';         
}
```

Hopefully with the help of the link above you should be able to see the basics of what I wrote out for you.

Some notes:

- Stop making variables that are simply copies of other variables, it's inefficient and confusing.
- (Try to) Stop sending data to new PHP pages as GET URL values such as `/newpage.php?treatp=".$var."`. This is very probably very insecure.
- A more specific answer will need a full explanation from you of your MySQL tables, if nessecary please edit your question and add them.
- Try and move away from using timestamps and treating timestamp variables as mathematical entities, and use the `DateTime` object instead.
- Really, to determine if a payment is made you should have a payment date value in your database (set when a payment is successful) and simply compare this date to the value of the integer of the number of days payment covers, using the `->diff()` method illustrated above.

[image]

[Further information on Goat Vaccinations](https://www.britishgoatsociety.com/about-us/health/vaccines/)